# how to check the nested subdocument field is true or false

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i need to check a specific nested subdocument field in the document true or false,
i know my scheme is more nested but i dont have any other option

this is my document model

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63844ad47389ec0e773d73f3"
  },
  "bid": "637b4ec45688ffbe092af629",
  "name": "hari",
  "start_date": "2022-25-11",
  "end_date": "2022-28-11",
  "start_time": "09:00:00",
  "end_time": "11:00:00",
  "excuse": "10",
  "slots": [
    {
      "date": "2022-11-23T00:00:00.000Z",
      "slots": [
        {
          "uid": null,
          "start_time": "01:00 AM",
          "end_time": "01:30 AM",
          "attachment": null,
          "available": true,    // need to check this field
          "status": null,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63844ad47389ec0e773d73f5"
          }
        },
        {
          "uid": null,
          "start_time": "01:35 AM",
          "end_time": "02:05 AM",
          "attachment": null,
          "available": true,
          "status": null,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63844ad47389ec0e773d73f6"
          }
        }
        
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63844ad47389ec0e773d73f4"
      }
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-11-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "slots": [
        {
          "uid": null,
          "start_time": "01:00 AM",
          "end_time": "01:30 AM",
          "attachment": null,
          "available": true,
          "status": null,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63844ad47389ec0e773d73fc"
          }
        },
        {
          "uid": null,
          "start_time": "01:35 AM",
          "end_time": "02:05 AM",
          "attachment": null,
          "available": true,
          "status": null,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63844ad47389ec0e773d73fd"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63844ad47389ec0e773d73fb"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}]
```

i need to check the  slots.slots.avaiable is true or not how to check this field
can anyone suggest me the exact query to find this ?

specification

node : v14.17.3
mongoose: ^6.6.5,
mogodb: Atlas

Comment: There are 4 fields with this path in this document. What is your expected result

Comment: I need to check whether the given sub document I'ds available is true are false. In this case assume I need to check the subdocument id 63844ad47389ec0e773d73f5  's  available field is true or not